# Naming a new object after a string?

Tags: java

I want to have a method that will create an object of the class being and automatically name it `"b1"` for the first object, `"b2"` for the second, and so on. Can I use a `String` as the name of a new object? If it's possible, how do I do it?

```
class being {
    static int count = 0;
    String name;

    void createbeing(){
        name = "b" + Integer.toString(count);
        being name = new being(); //Here I want to insert the String name as the name of the object
        count++;
    }

}
```

Comment: You should explain *why* you want to do that because it is unlikely that you really need to do that.

Comment: If I had a quarter for every time this was asked here,... Please understand that 1) the variable name does not == the object name, and in fact object's don't have names, and objects can be assigned to more than one variable. 2) the variable name really isn't important to the running program, but rather it's main importance is to write human-readable code that's easy to debug. 3) the variable name for all intents and purposes doesn't even exist in running code. 4) What **is** important are object *references*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, this is not possible in Java; you cannot create variables at runtime. You could, however, maintain a [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) that maps `String` identifiers to their corresponding `Being`s. i.e.

```
Map<String, Being> map = new HashMap<String, Being>();
...
name = "b" + Integer.toString(count);
map.put(name, new Being());
count++;
```

Note that I have assumed a more conventional name: `Being` as opposed to `being`.

Answer (score 3):

In your code you are just creating a local reference of the class object in the function "createbeing()",and the above declared String "name" is hidden in the "createbeing()" function scope by the reference "name" that you are declaring as a reference of the object of class being.

Answer (score 2):

> Can I use a string as a name of an object?

No. The usual way to do that would be to use one of the `List` implementations and add the objects to it, e.g.:

```
class being{
    static List<being> beings = new LinkedList<being>();

    void createbeing(){
        beings.add(new being());
    }
}
```

(I'm **not** advocating using a static list of the beings. There's almost certainly a better approach to the larger problem you're trying to solve. But that was the minimal mod to the code you presented.)

Alternately, you could use a `Map` and actually get the names you wanted (`"b1"` and so on):

```
class being{
    static int count = 0;
    static Map<String,being> beings = new HashMap<String,being>();

    void createbeing(){
        count++;
        beings.add("b" + count, new being());
    }
}
```

(Same caveat as above.)

Answer (score 2):

Add a name attribute to your class (which should be named `Being`, BTW, and not `being`), and to its constructor:

```
public class Being
    private String name;

    public Being(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Then create your objects:

```
void createBeing(){
    name = "b" + Integer.toString(count);
    Being being = new Being(name);
    // TODO: do something with the Being object
    count++;
}
```

That's how an object can have a name. Don't confuse objects, and variables.

Comment: So far this is the best way..that answer his question

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be achieved this way. If the name of the variable is important for you, store as the keys of a `Map<String,being>`

```
Map<String,being> map = new HashMap<String,being>();
map.put("b1", new being());
```